# (iOS) How can I Reuse an UIImageView in another View?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I have a view controller with a UIScrollView with a heap of UIImageViews as subviews. There is a segue to another view controller but i want to reuse the UIImages that are already in memory rather than load them again for efficiency's sake. But if I point my new UIImageView to an existing one, nothing shows up.

I had to use an intermediate pointer variable (imageViewPointer) as if I assign it directly in the prepareForSegue method, the NSLog's from each view controller would show different addresses. This workaround NSLogs show the same address but still nothing shows up.

If I use reassign the .image property instead, the image shows up but the images from the first view controller are load asynchronously so the .image property might change.

In the first view controller

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    NextViewController *nextViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    nextViewController.imageViewPointer = [[myScrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:myIndex];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[myScrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:myIndex]);
}
```

In the second view controller

```
@interface nextViewController : UIViewController

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageViewPointer;

@implementation nextViewController

@synthesize imageView, imageViewPointer;

{
    self.imageView = self.imageViewPointer;

//    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];   Doesn't help

    NSLog(@"IMAGE VIEW POINTER = %@", self.imageViewPointer);
    NSLog(@"IMAGE VIEW = %@", self.imageView);

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply assign a view like that, it won't appear in the view hierarchy of your current view controller's view. You'll need to do something like:

```
[self.view addSubview: imageView];
```

However, I wouldn't recommend that. It is better to just assign the image of the view to the image of the other view.

```
self.imageView.image = self.imageViewPointer.image;
```

Comment: `[self.view addSubview: imageView];` ...even if the UIImageView is created in interface builder? | `self.imageView.image = self.imageViewPointer.image;`... This works but as I said, the images are loaded asynchronously (SDWebImage) so if the user is too fast, the image property will be set to either nil or a placeholder and i will be getting a pointer to that. I was hoping by reusing the same object, the image would update when it has loaded from the web like it does in the first view controller.

Comment: If you are using SDWebImage you should be using the `UIImageView (WebCache)` `setImageWithURL:` method instead.

Comment: There is nothing special about the imageView simply because it was created with interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

Either you reuse the `UIImage` or the method you are doing is a bit wrong as you are assigning the `imageViewPointer` to `imageView` which is(imageViewPointer) not a subview of your view controller's view. So add subview `imageViewPointer` or `imageView` after assigning `imageViewPointer`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly but imageView is an IBOutlet for a UIImageView created in interface builder, so it is already a subview of the main UIView. imageViewPointer is just an intermediate variable. I did this because if I set `nextViewController.imageView` property directly from the first view controller's prepareForSegue method, for some reason the addresses in the NSLog's don't match. By using nextViewController.imageViewPointer as an intermediary I get all NSLog's outputting the same address which is what I want.

Comment: See your imageView is connected to IB but when you re-assign it with imageViewPointer now your xib UIImageView and imageView are different as you assign it. And your new imageView is not a subview of your view.